# search for text in breeze.js

Tags: breeze

I want to search for a text in with Breeze.js

```
var qu = new breeze.EntityQuery("Projects")
                    .where("Name", "startsWith", newValue);
```

This statement only shows the projects that start with the text i typed in my search box.

How is it possible to also search for the text also if it's in the middle of a projects name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use as below:

```
var qu = new breeze.EntityQuery("Projects")
                .where("Name", FilterQueryOp.Contains, newValue);
```

> FilterQueryOp is an 'Enum' containing all of the valid Predicate filter operators for an EntityQuery.

The Query Operations are defined in http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/FilterQueryOp.html

`Contains` also has an alias "substringof". SO you could do as below.

```
var qu = new breeze.EntityQuery("Projects")
                .where("Name", "substringof", newValue);
```